# What is a good way to go about getting the Skilled Huntress achievement in Dead by daylight?

Tags: achievements, dead-by-daylight

This achievement is obtained by downing survivors with your hatchets 100 times from 24+ meters away as the Huntress. Though I've been getting better at it, I'm still a little off on my shots, so I need to rely more on the perks I bring.

What perks other than [Barbecue and Chili](https://deadbydaylight.fandom.com/wiki/Barbecue_%26_Chilli) and [Bitter Murmur](https://deadbydaylight.fandom.com/wiki/Bitter_Murmur) would be good for accomplishing my goal?

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with an answer for my own question based on the newest Dead by Daylight update that is soon to be released, which contains the Legion killer. It just seems that I had to stew over it for a bit to find it out. To get this achievement, one ***could*** run add-ons and perks such as these:

- Add-ons

  Iridescent Head - Instant down hatchets; 4 less max hatchets.

  Infantry Belt - 2 more max hatchets.
- Perks

  Discordance III - When 2 survivors work on a generator at the same time, that 
                    generator's aura shines yellow for 12 seconds.

  Iron Maiden III - You search lockers 50% faster; Survivors that exit lockers suffer 
                    exposed for 15 seconds and are revealed for 4 seconds.

  Barbecue and Chili III - When you hook a survivor, all survivors at least 40 meters 
                           away are revealed for 4 seconds; You gain 25% bonus 
                           bloodpoints for every time you hook a survivor for the first 
                           time.

  Bitter Murmur III - Every time a generator is repaired, all survivors within 16 
                      meters of that generator are revealed for 5 seconds; When the 
                      last generator is repaired, all survivors are revealed for 10 
                      seconds.

Comment: I'd also recommend using a Coldwind offering because it's so open. Slugging would also let you get the maximum use out of your add-ons because the survivors would take longer to die.

Comment: Iridescent Head now sets your maximum hatchets to 1. Infantry belt cannot increase it further and so has no effect, so the add-ons do not combo together any more.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to relying on specific builds and your own skill, there's something else you can do to speed up your progress on this achievement a little bit, especially in matches where you're otherwise not doing too well. It will unfortunately not work every time because it depends on the map, but it can still help.

When the survivors manage to open the exit gate, they will often wait in the exit area in case someone else needs help, or they'll just stick around for fun. When this happens, approach the gate from a distance, and stop when you think you're still more than 24 meters away (this will not work on some maps or exit gate configurations, as there may be obstacles in the way). Then, simply stay there and try to hit the survivors with your hatchets, occasionally walking to a nearby locker to reload. Given the distance, the survivors are unlikely to leave, they won't feel threatened as they could still just crawl out if you down them from so far away. Sometimes, especially if there's more of them, they may let the hatchets hit them on purpose, as they'll get points for healing each other. Othertimes, they will make a game out of dodging your throws, but often enough you'll still hit them eventually if you predict their movements and change up the timing of your throws, which can actually also serve as a pretty decent target practice session.

Results may vary of course, but I found this to be a pretty fun endgame activity for both sides that will slowly but surely increase the counter for your achievement.